# Позиционирование элемента в модальном окне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, modal

Есть модальное окно в котором находятся текстбоксы в 2 столбца и в первом столбце под текстбоксами есть изображение. Но оно почему то сдвигается немного провее относительно всех текстбоксов. Как сделать так что бы оно начиналось на одном уровне со всеми текстбоксами в своём столбце.

```
<div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    @Html.Label("Автомобиль:")
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Price, "Цена")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPrice", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Count, "Количество на складе")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtCount", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "Марка")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMarkName", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, "Модель")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtModelName", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, "Изображение Автомобиля", new { @style = "padding-right: 50px" })
                                        <input id="btnAddPicture" type="button" value="Обзор" class="btn btn-secondary" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <img id="autoPicture" class="col-sm-10" src="~/Content/auto.jpg" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    @Html.Label("Комплектация:")
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Engine, "Двигатель")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Engine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtEngine", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Power, "Мощность")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Power, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPower", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.ReleaseYear, "Год выпуска")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.ReleaseYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtYear", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.DriveType, "Тип привода")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.DriveType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtDriveType", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Transmission, "КПП")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Transmission, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtTransmission", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Body, "Кузов")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtBody", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxSpeed, "Максимальная скорость")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxSpeed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMaxSpeed", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight, "Вес")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtWeight", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxFuelVolume, "Бак")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxFuelVolume, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtFuel", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Color, "Цвет")
                                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Color, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtColor", @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать, можете детальнее обяснить вашу проблему, в начале у вас была проблема с картинкой которую сдвигало вправо.

Comment: @IvanTokar не картинку сдвигало. А текст темы сдвигало в лево когда я убирал содержимое img. Я хочу сделать слево картинку высотой в несколько строк. А справо что бы было несколько тексбоксов на против этой картинки. А у меня получается что на против картинки только 1 текстбокс не важно какой ширины а все последующие идут уже ниже картинки.

Comment: @IvanTokar всё хорошо сделал по вашему примеру, но теперь снова проблема с небольшим отступом картинки от левого края. Я смог её убрать только с помощью если убирал у img class и сам назначал размеры в style, а вот так по нормальному не получается. Я подредактирую вопрос, вставлю последний вариант кода и скриншот.

Comment: @IvanTokar по сути вопрос вернулся к своему изначальному состоянию) Как сможете поглядите пожалуйста.

Comment: @IvanTokar я подозреваю что дело в том что у img есть свой собственный col-sm но если его не ставить то картинка становиться огромной и уходит даже за экран.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как можно этого избежать.

Comment: Картинка не может быть колонкой, не применяйте класс .col-* к картинкам, грид система это каркас, его нельзя навешивать стилями которий может его сломать, а также нельзя стили грида вешать на что угодно, посмотрите какие стили у .row .col-*, там есть «маржины» «падинги», и прочее что вам мешает.

Comment: @IvanTokar и что мне тогда нужно сделать что бы картинка не съезжала и не была огромной? Как я понимаю убрать класс col, тогда съезжать не будет. Но тогда размер у неё будет очень большой. Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте ей класс `.img-fluid`

Comment: @IvanTokar ничего не изменилось, изображение огромное. Может дело в том что у меня bootstrap в проекте Bootstrap v3.3.7. Просто сейчас по умолчанию когда создаёшь в visual studio 2017 проект mvc именно Bootstrap v3.3.7 добавляется в проект. Если дело в этом под мою версию бутстрапа есть какое то решение?

Comment: [Здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images-responsive) для вашей версии  v3.3.7. Для v3.3.7 класс назывался `.img-responsive`

Comment: @IvanTokar вот мой пример `<div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <img id="autoPicture" class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/auto.jpg" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>` так всё работает, но картинка само собой во все пол экрана по ширене становиться так как находится в левом столбце. Поэтому я начинаю ограничивать и вместо `col` пишу у дива `col-sm-8` например.

Comment: И в этом случае если уменьшить контейнер, картинка снова съезжает на такое же расстояние как и раньше от левого края? Почему так происходит? Наверное с классом col-sm-8 применяются дополнительно border или что?

Comment: Вот [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) для вашей версии, там нет еще класса `.col`, он появился в более поздней версии на Флексах, по умолчанию у грида максимум 12 колонок, не превышайте это число, далее для картинки должен быть установлен `max-width: 100%`, или вы используете стили Bootstrap или свои, это не важно, но это позволит картинке быть адаптивной и принимать размер блока в котором она находится. Ознакомьтесь с документами Bootstrap, не пытайтесь угадать как правильно, как правило это занимает больше времени.

Comment: @IvanTokar а разьве класс img-responsive не выставляет по умолчанию max width на 100%? Ну по сути у меня col работает нормально для всего остального.

Answer (score 1):

Я привел пример внизу как нужно разбить на две колонки ваше модальное окно, обратите внимание что я использовал `.container-fluid`, в отличие от `.container` он занимает 100% места по горизонтали, а не адаптируется в зависимости от [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Картинки тоже нужно адаптировать и в Bootstrap для этого также есть [инструменты](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/content/images/).

```css
.test {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="test">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            img
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            text field 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            text field 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            text field 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            text field 4
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ivan спасибо хороший пример.

Answer (score 0):

Поместите его к остальным `col-sm-5` в контейнер `<div class="row">`, он в него не входит по судя по вашему коду, или поместите в отдельный `row`

Comment: Ivan пробовал в отдельный row тот же результат. Там все строки если что каждая в своём row.

Comment: Ivan попробовал сделать ещё 1 row и добавит туда свою картинку, с остальными текстбоксами которые должны идти в правом ряду. И вроде бы всё нормально и всё сдвинулось как нужно, но есть 1 нюанс. Если картинка есть, и у текстбоксов которые должны быть справа есть offset тога все текстбоксы уходят ниже картинки, а вот если убрать offset тогда с картинкой всё нормально, но тогда проблема если картинки нет, как эт оможно исправить? Код и скрины привожу в конце вопроса.

Comment: Ivan я добавил данные в вопрос и дописал формулировку, посдкажите пожалуйста если можете.

Comment: Разделите на две колонки ваш шаблон, а внутрь каждой положить то что нужно и ничего у вас не будет сьезжать, пример: row внитри два col-sm-*, а вних каждого по одному row и colы, у вас есть возможность влаживать row>col>row>col ... почитайте в документации по Bootstrap о гридах [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Comment: Ivan решил последовать вашему совету и потренироваться на codepen. Скинул скрин в конце вопроса. Создал несколько row а внутри них col'ы. Сделал как мне нужно для своего примера высокий col внутри row на половину строки. Но не как не могу добавить несколько узких строчке на вторую половину. Как мне это сделать? Всё что я запихиваю внутрь row где уже лежит высокий col становиться тоже высоким на второй половине.

Comment: Ivan попробовал даже предпоследний row на скрине сделать вот таким вот `<div class="row">
    <div id="txt" class="col-6" style="height: 200px">1</div>
    <div id="txb" class="col-6" style="height: 40px">3</div>
    <div id="txb" class="col-6" style="height: 40px">4</div>
  </div>` специально как бы вторую половину умешить руками что бы она была справа пока что не закончится вся высота левого col'а но так тоже не получилось первый правый col на 40 пикселей появился справа как и нужно, а второй уже на следующей строке. Как быть подскажите пожалуйста? Не получается реализовать задачу.